# Poor image quality in VirtualBox with Ubuntu VM running on Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, display

I have an ASUS laptop running Windows 10. 
I have Oracle VirtualBox with a Linux Ubuntu VM.

I've had no problems until this week when I started Ubuntu in VirtualBox
and everything visual (display of icons, fonts, etc..) was of low quality
(and perhaps bigger than usual),
including in the VirtualBox graphical interface itself.

The difference in quality is noticeable in the screenshots. 
The one on the left is the current (new), bad quality display;
the one on the right shows good quality.

[image: Screenshot with bad quality]
        [image: Screenshot with good quality]

The bad quality VirtualBox graphical interface:

[image: Screenshot of bad quality VirtualBox graphical interface]

I've tried to use the VirtualBox settings and the Ubuntu settings to change resolution but without success, as the quality remains poor.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: "including in the VirtualBox graphical interface itself" - please include screenshots of this (you can [edit] the question). How did you take the good screenshot?

Comment: Just realized what you where asking, had taken it a while back, got lucky not to delete it.

Comment: (1) FWIW, it looks like, while the font (“Activities”) is bigger now than it was before, the icons are smaller.   (2) The image of the VirtualBox main window that you posted looks pretty crisp to me.  Are you sure that that isn’t an old copy of the original, good quality display?  (Why did you say that you “had taken it a while back, got lucky not to delete it.”?)

Comment: I messed with the icons size while trying to solve the issue. The virtualbox interface is different much bigger letters and icons, with less quality.

Comment: @Scott Look at the "Running" arrow, penguin's edges, VM icon and toolbar buttons

Comment: Do you have scaling enabled on Windows 10?  Have you tried to "Let Windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry" under Settings\Display\Scale and layout\advanced scaling settings?

Comment: No, I tried enabling it. Know what do I do?